# String split token=value in java and regex

Tags: java, regex, split

I have this string

```
token1=value1Token2=value2Token3[12]=value3
```

where `tokenX` might be a string with numbers (e.g.: myToken12 or my2Token)
and `valueX` just numbers or symbols (e.g.: `123123 or {{1, 2}, 3, 4}`)

that I'd like to transform into this array:

```
['token1=value1', 'token2=value2', 'token3[12]=value3']
```

example of string I might have:

```
String s = na23me=12341234las4tName={{0,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0}}stree2t[696]=764545457OK
```

I tried with split and matcher ...

this question has been already posted but this is different as it is more general (token=value) where value in the previous question was just a number or in a different post symbols. 
I'd like to have a general answer here.

thanks.

**MORE DETAIL:**

with this string:

```
String s = na23me=12341234las4tName=654567stree2t[696]=764545457OK
```

this solution:

```
String[] tokens = s.split("(?<==\\d{1,1000})(?=[a-zA-Z])");
```

works, but I might have as "value" something like this {1, 2, 3} that I'd like to consider. that's why is different.

**ONE LEVEL MORE**
what about if I want to include the "TEST" too?

e.g.:

```
conf=0ticket[0,9]="TEST"config={0,0,0}platform_id=121212
```

I've tried with this

```
String[] tokens = buffer.split("(?<==\\d{1,1000}|\\W| **\"\\w\"**)(?=[a-zA-Z])");
```

**EXPECTED:**

```
At the end just managing the "STRING" as "value", but it shouldn't be a big issue as is into the double quote.


['conf=0', 'ticket[0,9]="TEST"', 'config={0,0,0}', 'platform_id=121212']
```

doesn't work ..idea?

Comment: Show what you have tried already and tell us where it failed.

Comment: because valueX could be just numbers and symbols (e.g.: {) NOT char

Comment: split your input according to `(?i)(?<!^)(?=token)`

Comment: So an example input is: `token1=111Token2=222Token3[12]=33my2Token=444`?

Comment: token1=111Token2=222Token3[12]=33my2Token={{0, 0, 1}, 2, 2}

Comment: your solution is quite close, the problem is that I observed that doesn't work in this case (just symbols):
token1={{0, 0, 1}, 2, 2}Token2={{0, 0, 1}, 2, 2} Token3[12]={{0, 0, 1}, 2, 2}my2Token={{0, 0, 1}, 2, 2}

Comment: **where tokenX might be a string with numbers (e.g.: myToken12 or my2Token) and valueX just numbers or symbols (e.g.: 123123 or {{1, 2}, 3, 4})**
    ;-)

Comment: @anubhava: this is working :-)    String[] tokens = s.split("(?<==\\d{1,1000} **|\\W** )(?=[a-zA-Z])");

Comment: @Kasper In your example from few coments earlier `token1={{0, 0, 1}, 2, 2}Token2={{0, 0, 1}, 2, 2} Token3[12]={{0, 0, 1}, 2, 2}my2Token={{0, 0, 1}, 2, 2}` you have space between `{{0, 0, 1}, 2, 2} Token3` but in your description from question I don't see any spaces between `value1Token2`. So which is wrong, description of your data or example?

Comment: @Kasper: Remember to always format your code and do add your expected output for each input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your input string is getting more and more complex. Here is one regex that seems to be working for all of your provided inputs:

```
void getTokens(String s) {
   String[] toks = s.split( "(?<==(?>\"[^\"=]{1,1000}\"|\\P{L}{1,1000})) *(?=\\p{L})" );
   for (String tok: toks)
      System.out.printf("=> <%s>%n", tok);
}
```

**Testing:**

```
getTokens("conf=0ticket[0,9]=\"TEST\"config={0,0,0}platform_id=121212");
=> <conf=0>
=> <ticket[0,9]="TEST">
=> <config={0,0,0}>
=> <platform_id=121212>

getTokens("na23me=12341234las4tName={{0,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0}}stree2t[696]=764545457OK");
=> <na23me=12341234>
=> <las4tName={{0,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0}}>
=> <stree2t[696]=764545457>
=> <OK>

getTokens("na23me=12341234las4tName=654567stree2t[696]=764545457OK");
=> <na23me=12341234>
=> <las4tName=654567>
=> <stree2t[696]=764545457>
=> <OK>
```

**Explanation:**

Regex uses a lookbehind and a lookahead for splitting:

- `(?<==(?>\"[^\"=]{1,1000}\"|\\P{L}{1,1000}))` is a positive lookbehind that makes sure current position is preceded by a `=` followed by one of these:

  - A double quoted string of max 1000 in length OR
  - 1 to 1000 non unicode letters
- `(?>foo|bar)` is called an [**Atomic Group**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html)
- `(?=\\p{L})` is a positive lookahead that makes sure there is a unicode letter following current position